# Integer Counter with SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, counter, android-sharedpreferences

I have a problem with my counter. I'v used this as my template: 
[Continuing integer counter from sharedpreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20068986/continuing-integer-counter-from-sharedpreferences)

But if I stop the app and reopen it and tap one button the Counter goes to 0. But if I only go home and reopen the app the counter goes higher. How can I fix this?

```
counter = Integer.ParseInt(userString); //this line.
```

Doesn't work for me. Please help me.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve here. Please elaborate your goals. Also the integer counter is not initialized. You need to give it a value and then make sure it gets re-initialized by overriding the onPause and onRestart methods.

Comment: @SanVed I like something like Cookie Clicker. How can I do this that after I restart the App to start from the number before i closed the app. Sorry for my bad englisch.

Comment: ???????????? @SanVed

Comment: So you want a counter. You basically open the app and then click to increase the count and then you want the value to be stored right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

now I have it done. It Works. I've used:

```
counter = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(userString));
```

Thanks for @SanVed to answer me.

Comment: I'm welcome. But I am not sure how my comment helped you.